# Crystal Report Refreshing Issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

1) I created a Crystal Report in my machine and exported that reports in my local path and using that rpt files in my windows application for loading the report in crystal report viewer.

2) When i am refreshing the report in Crystal Report, its connecting to sybase database and taking the latest data and displaying in crystal report.

3) Now i developed the code in windows application using C# and loading those reports in crystal report viewer using .rpt file. its loading fine.

4) But when i am trying to refresh the report using "Refresh" button in Crystal Report Viewer, it asked for parameter and i given the parameter, then it displays a Database Logon screen with the servername, username, database and asked for password only, but after giving password, i am getting the message "**Logon Failed**" and not refreshed the latest data in crystal report viewer.

please help me and give the detail and clear step, how to use the refresh functionality to get the latest data.

Regards,
Ramachandran.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the parameter to appear or *reuse the parameter when refresh*, you could use something like:

```
yourCrViewer.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
```

If you are using the *xsd* files to create your report, sometimes with *invalid path*, the *logon screen* can appear. ( I do not have more details on how you doing it) 
What you can do is, try *verify database* in your crystal reports (if you  have copied the crystal report over to your windows c# application), this *may* prompt for you to give location of your *xsd* file, and with valid location, the *logon prompt* will not appear anymore.